# Way to defensive check value assigned to public const variable in immutable class in C++17?

Tags: c++17, immutability

Coming back to C++ after a hiatus in Java. Attempting to create an immutable object and after working in Java, a public const variable seems the most sensible (like Java final).

```
public:
     const int A;
```

All well and good, but if I want to defensive check this value, how might I go about it.  The code below seems strange to me, but unlike Java final members, I can't seem to set A in the constructor after defensive checks (compiler error).

```
MyObj::MyObj(int a) : A(a) {
        if (a < 0)
            throw invalid_argument("must be positive");
    }
```

A public const variable for A seems like a clearer, cleaner solution than a getter only with a non const int behind it, but open to that or other ideas if this is bad practice.

Comment: What compile error do you get?

Comment: error: uninitialized const member in 'const int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: That sounds like you're not showing us the whole picture. Do you have any other constructors? You need to initialize `A` in all of them.

Comment: I do not, at least not that I've defined.  Should I have deleted some default something?  This is the first thing I'm doing in C++ again, likely to be making mistakes.

Comment: And just to be clear, that error is if I remove : A(a) and instead put A = a after the defensive check, at the bottom of the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I see: so your example code isn't what you're actually doing? Regardless I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm obviously being confusing.  If I were doing this in Java, i'd set A = a after the defensive check, seems more readable.  I cannot in C++, due to compile error.  Hence I've ended up with the code as written above, but it seems awkward to me accordingly.

Comment: C++ doesn’t need “immutable types”: if you want an immutable `MyObj`, you write that as `const MyObj`, without permanently preventing assigning to a `MyObj` elsewhere in the code where that might be appropriate.

Comment: @DavisHerring  This class represents something loaded from a source of truth that should never be modified again.  Changing the value after construction is never intended.  Are you suggesting a pattern that returns const objects or saying it should be understood by everyone that this value should never be modified, but not programatically enforced as such?  If the former, I'd love to hear how you would design it.  I could picture a factory pattern and private constructor.

Comment: @Evan: If objects of this class will only ever have one (shared!) value, and yet you still need a class (to initialize its several members together), you want a singleton (which can be made `const` if it’s a function-local static).  If not, it seems reasonable that a client might want to change the value they’re using, and assignment should be allowed.  You can layer access control on top of the singleton strategy, or on your factory function, if you think misuse is highly likely.  In no case is a const non-static data member necessary.

Comment: I ended up throwing this idea away and going back to non const members private members with public getters.  Seems like I was swimming up stream.  I do quite like the Java final construct after having grow accustomed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example as it stands should work fine:

```cpp
class MyObj {
public:
  const int var;
  MyObj(int var) : var(var) {
    if (var < 0)
       throw std::invalid_argument("must be positive");
  }
};
```

([Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e777adb99ee3e9a), or [with out-of-line constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55804679788e7cbf))

If you intend that `MyObj` will always be immutable, then a `const` member is 
probably fine. If you want the variable to be immutable in general, but still have the possibility to overwrite the entire object with an assignment, then better to have a `private` variable with a getter:

```cpp
class MyObj {
  int var;
public:
  MyObj(int var) : var(var) {
    if (var < 0)
      throw std::invalid_argument("must be positive");
  }

  int getVar() const { return var; }
};

// now allows
MyObj a(5);
MyObj b(10);
a = b;
```

## Edit

Apparently, what you want to do is something like

```cpp
  MyObj(int var) {
    if (var < 0)
       throw std::invalid_argument("must be positive");
    this->var = var;
  }
```

This is not possible; once a `const` variable has a value it cannot be changed. Once the body (`{}` bit) of the constructor starts, `const` variables already have a value, though in this case the value is "undefined" since you're not setting it (and the compiler is throwing an error because of it).

Moreover, there's actually no point to this. There is no efficiency difference in setting the variable after the checks or before them, and it's not like any external observers will be able to see the difference regardless since the `throw` statement will unroll the stack, deconstructing the object straight away.

Comment: I didn't clarify that.  I intend the object to be immutable, and deleted the default copy constructor and copy assignment constructors accordingly.

Comment: In that case a `const` member is fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  I am curious if there's another way you'd go about this instead of what I'm doing.  Does this construct seem awkward as a C++ dev or readable?

Comment: This way is fine, and perfectly readable. I tend to steer away from exceptions in general, though, so I might just assert or have a `private` constructor and instead use a `static` factory method returning a `std::optional<MyObj>` that does the checks for me. (Of course I don't know your circumstances, so this might be a case where an exception is the correct option!)

Comment: This class is constructed from data from an external data source, which could give me something entirely unexpected and out of my control.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, @N.Shead is right: if you need to do checks more extensive than this, or if it is expensive to create the object then have it fail, you can use a factory function/method. Though I wouldn't have it return an `optional`, that to me seems wierd and insufficient (where's the error info?) - the factory ought to _create_ something or throw, but if you want to monadify it then some form of `either` monad should be used so you can return error information - why did the factory fail?

Comment: @davidbak Fair point about error info; in this case I didn't feel it was necessary, but in the general case you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the [answer by N. Shead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084758/751579) is the regular practice - but you can also consider:

1. Create domain-specific types and use them instead of general primitives.  E.g., if your field is a telephone number, have a type `TelephoneNumber` which, in its constructor (or factory), taking a string, does all the telephone number validation you'd like (and throws on invalid).  Then you write something like:

   ```
   class Contact {
     const TelephoneNumber phone_;
    public:
     Contact(string phone) : phone_(phone) { ... }
     ...
   ```

   When you do this the constructor for `TelephoneNumber` taking a string argument will be called when initializing the field `phone_` and the validation will happen.

   Using domain-specific types this way is discussed on the web under the name "primitive obsession" as a "code smell".

   (The problem with this approach IMO is that you pretty much have to use it everywhere, and from the start of your project, otherwise you start having to have explicit (or implicit) casting all over the place and your code looks like crap and you can never be sure if the value you have has been validated or not. If you're working with an existing codebase it is nearly impossible to retrofit it completely though you might just start using it for particularly important/ubiquitous types.)
2. Create validation methods that take and return some value, and which perform the validation necessary - throwing when invalid otherwise returning its argument.  Here's an example validator:

   ```
   string ValidatePhoneNumber(string v) {
     <some kind of validation throwing on invalid...>
     return v;
   }
   ```

   And use it as follows:

   ```
   class Contact {
     const string phone_;
    public:
     Contact(string phone) : phone_(ValidatePhoneNumber(phone)) { ... }
   ```

   I've seen this used when an application or library is doing so much validation of domain-specific types that a small library of these domain-specific validator methods has been built up and code readers are used to them.  I wouldn't really consider it idiomatic, but it does have the advantage that the validation is right out there in the open where you can see it.